# Add Reference dynamically to my project

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop

I am Developping an Add-In for Microsoft Word.
In my Add-In i am using a reference to file "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll" so i can use word objects.

In case the development machine has word 2007 installed, the file to be included in references is version 12
in case word 2010 is installed, the file should be version 14.

how can i build my add in and make  it work regardless of which version of Word is installed on the machine (in other word tell my application to automatically detect which version of office is installed and use the appropriate interop file automatically)?

Answer (score 2):

If your actual code is making reference to the items in the given assembly, trying to hook into a different version could actually cause errors (e.g. if certain method signatures have been changed). In most cases, the best strategy would be to produce different builds to target the different DLL versions, and install the correct build on the user's machine.

There are strategies you can use to make this easier, like wrapping your calls to this library in a set of interfaces, and then having two main "plugin" assemblies that provide implementations for the interfaces, but which target different DLLs when they implement them. The software can load the implementation bindings dynamically by configuration, similar to the way popular Dependency Injection frameworks do. That way, if a method signature changes from one version to the other, you can just change a single class and the rest of your code will still work as-is.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how can the software load the implementation bindings dynamically by configuration? Say for example i create two wrappers IOffice.Wrapper.12.dll (which will reference office 12) and IOffice,Wrapper.14.dll (which will reference office 14), can i still install both wrappers or only one?

Comment: @Zee99: You could put both dll files on the user's computer, and when the program gets initialized you could only load the one that you need. One class in each assembly could implement a "bootstrapping" interface by initializing all of your factory classes. At runtime, you load the DLL and scan the assembly for a class that implements the given interface. Then you instantiate and run that particular class. So when your code says `CopyPasteUtilFactory.Get()`, you'll get a `CopyPasteUtil` that's implemented in `IOffice.Wrapper.XX.dll`.

Comment: @Zee99: Or even better, a DI framework like Ninject will take care of the hard part. You just include one or more Module classes in IOffice.Wrapper.XX.dll to create your bindings. When your program is starting up, tell Ninject to load the correct assembly. Then  whenever one of your classes depends on an `ICopyPasteUtil`, the correct implementation will get injected into it.